# Sorted HTML table

Tags: sort, html, table

I need a very quick and easy way to sort HTML tables. The table rows contain images that should stay with their appropriate row. I tried pasting my HTML into Libre Office calc, but the images are not pasted into rows, so sorting is not possible.

BTW, I do not want a *sortable* table. I want a sorted table. When done, I just want a plain HTML table that I can paste into a blog page, but I want the items in the table sorted.

I want to start with my clean HTML table, paste it into an app, sort the table and get the new HTML source without any added styling or junk having been added. It seems simple, but I can't find a solution.

Example of a table I wish to sort:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
http-equiv="content-type">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<table style="text-align: left; width: 100%;" border="1" cellpadding="2"
cellspacing="2">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="vertical-align: top;"> <a
href="http://example.com/images/a"> <img
src="http://example.com/images/a_thumb.jpeg" alt="image of a"> </a> </td>
<td style="vertical-align: top;">a<br>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="vertical-align: top;"><a
href="http://example.com/images/f"> <img
src="http://example.com/images/f_thumb.jpeg" alt="image of f"> </a> </td>
<td style="vertical-align: top;">f<br>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="vertical-align: top;"><a
href="http://example.com/images/c"> <img
src="http://example.com/images/c_thumb.jpeg" alt="image of c"> </a> </td>
<td style="vertical-align: top;">c<br>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="vertical-align: top;"><a
href="http://example.com/images/b"> <img
src="http://example.com/images/b_thumb.jpeg" alt="image of b"> </a> </td>
<td style="vertical-align: top;">b<br>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<br>
<br>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How do you want to sort table? How is it structured?

Comment: I want to sort it alphanumerically in ascending order based on column 2 which contains item names. Column 1 is images.

Comment: Can you give an example input?

Comment: This seems better suited to [Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/)...

Comment: @jasonwryan - I disagree.

Comment: @MountainX sure: tell me what this has to do with Unix/Linux?

Comment: @jasonwryan - the problem is due to the lack of an HTML editor for Linux that has a table sorting feature. If I were working on OS X or Windows I wouldn't even need to ask the question. It is a Linux issue and I'm hopeful that there is a Linux way to solve it. The problem is about editing a document on my desktop. I cannot imagine that this question fits on Webmasters.

Comment: You said *"If I were working on OS X or Windows I wouldn't even need to ask the question"*.  What HTML editor would you use for this task in those OS?  Maybe you could look up for a similar program, or ask for any replacement for Linux in the [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: I decided to come at this from a different angle -- I can try to find out why Libre Office Calc doesn't behave as expected. I opened a new question for that. A solution to either approach would satisfy me, so I'll leave this question here.

Comment: @jim - Dreamweaver. And I did ask there.

Comment: I have not found a solution yet. Would appreciate any help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Ex editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ex_%28text_editor%29) (part of Vi/Vim) as demonstrated in the following shell command:

```
$ ex +"g/<tr/;,/tr>/join" +"/<table\_.\{-}\zs<tr/;,/table>/sort /.\{-}<a href/" +%p -scq! table.html | html2text 
[image of a]
a
[image of b]
b
[image of c]
c
[image of f]
f
```

<sup>Above example is using `html2text` command-line tool to display parsed HTML from stdin (install if required).</sup>

To save sorted table to the new file, replace `+%p -scq!` with `+'wq! sorted.html'`, so:

```
ex +"g/<tr/;,/tr>/join" +"/<table\_.\{-}\zs<tr/;,/table>/sort /.\{-}<a href/" +'wq! sorted.html' table.html
```

Explanation:

- `+"cmd"` - Executes Vim command.
- `g/<tr/;,/tr>/join` - Joins lines between `<tr/` and `tr>` (for easier sorting).
- `/<table\_.\{-}\zs<tr/;,/table>/` - Selects content between first `<tr/` and `/table>`.
- `sort /.\{-}<a href/` - Sort above selection for lines starting after `<a href/`.
- `+%p` - **P**rints buffer.
- `-scq!` - **S**ilently **q**uit the editor without saving.

Check out similar example [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/10289/467).